# Word for song sung by cover band, or not original singer?

Tags: adjectives

I can't remember the word used to describe a song sung by someone else and not the original person. Anyone can help me on that one? Thanks.

Comment: You already give the answer in your title: such a song is known as a ***cover (version)***.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I maybe thinking of a slang term then? What happen was when I put up a Michael Jackson song, being sung by someone else, my co-worker said "this isn't MJ, it's a ...". She didn't use the word "cover"

Comment: Possibly, if she likes Michael Jackson but not the cover version, she may have said something like _clone_, _wannabe_, _copycat_, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

A [cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_version) is a new recording of a previously recorded song.

Answer (score 1):

If the song is sung by a person or group that sounds like the original artist(s) *and* if that person or group performs primarily music of that original artist(s), they can be called either:

- a *"(famous artist such as Elvis) impersonator"*

or

- *"tribute band"* such as *"Rolling Stones tribute band"*

Comment: The first term I was going to suggest myself. I have another up my sleeve if and when the OP replies!

Comment: @Mari-LouA and Kristina, What if the song is not song by a band, like Michael Jackson. What would the word to describe that?

Comment: @MCHam I'm not sure I understand, but I was going to suggest an "impressionist singer" and something else, slightly more obscure, but I've forgotten now. An impersonator tends to dress and act like a famous person. An impressionist mimics a famous person's voice and mannerisms.

Comment: That is what my first bullet point references: If the person primarily plays songs by that one artist (Michael Jackson, for example), in the style of that artist, they could be called a "Michael Jackson Impersonator".  If they are singing a song by another artist but are not trying to look and sound like that artist, they can be called a cover artist - like this list from YouTube: http://www.thetoptens.com/best-youtube-cover-artists/

Answer (score 0):

"Rendition" is typically used in the context of classical music. It does not always imply 'not original' but in most usages it does.

Meaning: a performance or interpretation, especially of a dramatic role or piece of music